# Load StanfordNLP model Locally

Tags: python, pip, stanford-nlp, jupyterhub

I'm trying to load the English model for StanfordNLP (python) from my local machine, but am unable to find the proper import statements to do so. What commands can be used? Is there a pip installation available to load the english model?

I have tried using the download command to do so, however my machine requires all files to be added locally. I downloaded the english jar files from https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ but am unsure if I need both the English and the English KBP version.

Comment: command `download()` downloads .zip file with size 1.9GB and it has only 3 files .pt. In file .jar I see different files but there is no .pt. `download()` still is downloading on my computer and maybe it will uncompress it in more files like in .jar

Answer (score 3):

directory set for model download is /home/sf

`pip install stanfordnlp # install stanfordnlp`

`import stanfordnlp
stanfordnlp.download("en") # here  after 'Y' one set custom directory path`

`local_dir_store_model = "/home/sf"
english_model_dir = "/home/sf/en_ewt_models"
tokienizer_en_pt_file = "/home/sf/en_ewt_models/en_ewt_tokenizer.pt"`

`nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(models_dir=local_dir_store_model,processors = 'tokenize,mwt,lemma,pos')
doc = nlp("""One of the most wonderful things in life is to wake up and enjoy a cuddle with somebody; unless you are in prison"""")
doc.sentences[0].print_tokens()`

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear what you want to do.

If you want to run the all-Python pipeline, you can download the files and run them in Python code by specifying the paths for each annotator as in this example.

```
import stanfordnlp

config = {
    'processors': 'tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse', # Comma-separated list of processors to use
    'lang': 'fr', # Language code for the language to build the Pipeline in
    'tokenize_model_path': './fr_gsd_models/fr_gsd_tokenizer.pt', # Processor-specific arguments are set with keys "{processor_name}_{argument_name}"
    'mwt_model_path': './fr_gsd_models/fr_gsd_mwt_expander.pt',
    'pos_model_path': './fr_gsd_models/fr_gsd_tagger.pt',
    'pos_pretrain_path': './fr_gsd_models/fr_gsd.pretrain.pt',
    'lemma_model_path': './fr_gsd_models/fr_gsd_lemmatizer.pt',
    'depparse_model_path': './fr_gsd_models/fr_gsd_parser.pt',
    'depparse_pretrain_path': './fr_gsd_models/fr_gsd.pretrain.pt'
}
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(**config) # Initialize the pipeline using a configuration dict
doc = nlp("Van Gogh grandit au sein d'une famille de l'ancienne bourgeoisie.") # Run the pipeline on input text
doc.sentences[0].print_tokens()
```

If you want to run the Java server with the Python interface, you need to download the Java jar files and start the server.  Full info here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

Then you can access the server with the Python interface.  Full info here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/corenlp_client.html

But just to be clear, the jar files should not be used with the pure Python pipeline.  Those are for running the Java server.